# Save multiple instances in Julia - LightGraphs.jl

Tags: graph, julia

I'm using LightGraphs.jl package to create some graphs. I have a program which runs in many iterations. I need to draw the graph for each iteration and save each of them in separate files. Can someone please help me to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps this [LightGraphs.jl documentation page](http://juliagraphs.github.io/LightGraphs.jl/latest/integration/) will be helpful.  It shows several instances of creating and saving graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you modify the graph within this for loop, the pseudocode looks roughly like this:

```
for i = 1:n
  # modify the graph G here
  savegraph("iter-$i.jgz", G)
end
```

This will create one file per iteration.

If you want to save them all in one file, and you have enough memory, you can do this:

```
d = Dict()
for i = 1:n
  # modify graph G here
  d["iter-$i"] = G
end
savegraph("allmygraphs.jgz", d)
```

Note that this does not save the *visualization* of the graph; it saves the graph structure itself. You can then use any of the visualization tools (Plots, GraphPlot, ...) to view any of the graphs and/or save them in different formats. Just add the graph rendering / save method in place of, or after, the `savegraph` call.